# Is there a custom to go round the Sefer Torah with just the arava bundle on Hoshana Rabba?

Tags: lulav-etrog-arba-minim, hoshana-rabbah

There is a shiur [“HOSHANA RABBA SHIUR OF RABBI J.B. SOLOVEITCHIK BOSTON, 1969”](http://www.parsha.net/pdf/Devarim/Succos62.pdf) which discusses the custom of the arava on Hoshana Rabba.

In the shiur, the Rav is recorded as saying:

> On Hoshana Rabba, besides decorating the altar, might they also have
>   taken the arava in hand while marching around it seven times?
>   Otherwise, how can we consider the arava a remembrance of the Temple?
>   What possible commemoration can there be for the decoration of the
>   altar? **However, if in the Beis HaMikdash we had marched around the
>   altar with the arava as well, then by our marching around the Sefer
>   Torah on the bima today, we do, indeed, reflect the practice in the
>   Temple.**

The bold part of the text seems to suggest that we march around the Sefer Torah with the arava. (Does the Rav mean the arava in the lulav bundle?). I have never seen anyone make a hakafa with the arava.

Can someone please explain this passage?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%93_%D7%92